# How to create a showModelBottomSheet on new page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm Creating a login page to add field and this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
bottomsheet() {
  // BuildContext context = BuildContext as BuildContext;
  return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [],
        );
      });
}
```

but this will return as context will not be null. how can we create a showModelBottomSheet in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours, I get an idea from scratch, that's worked.

```
bottomSheet(context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [],
        );
      });
}
```

You have to pass context a parameter on the function because the stateful widget has context else the context will be null.
context has the tree of our widgets. so that can be inherited from our parent widget or screens.
Thank you.